# Difference between test execution time and real time

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, junit

I have a project with Spring which has integration tests with JUnit. When I run the tests, I can see the difference between execution time of the tests and real time. Real time (the time between I press "run test" and finished tests) is something like 1.5 times greater than "junit time".

Why does this difference exist? Is it induced by Spring context startup and shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

Execution time is just the amount of time for the test case. The real time is everything else. Spring context startup and shutdown. And any before and/or after methods.